# MASM32 - Implementing video

Tags: windows, video, assembly, masm32

I want to add a video to my game in MASM32. I looked it up on the web, and got zero results. How do I add a video in MASM32 and display it out on screen?

Comment: Do you plan on writing the code to read the video file, decode the data and display it on the screen yourself?  That's a pretty ambitious project for asm.  Or were you going to use features in the operation system to display the video?  In that case, you should probably tell us which OS you are using.

Comment: At the very least you need to mention what OS you're targeting. It would also help to know what sort of "video" you're trying to display.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 , Visual Studio 2013, i dont mind what type of video it needs to be . i want to load a video into a screen thats the only thing.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "video". Do you want to display a prerendered video file (eg. a movie)? How are you displaying graphics in your game now?

Comment: i got a "template" contains all the libraries  i need and some main files from school to display a window. I just wanted to ask if there is a function in c/c++/or anything i can use in asm, to display a video (like DrawImage function for hbitmap images).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... It *can* be done... but it's not going to be easy. You'll probably want to use [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/) (very good compatibility with all popular video formats), then learn about [COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It) (common-object-model) programming ([in MASM32](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=3118.0)) first. Then read [this post](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=3463.0) to try Yves's approach.